# RecyclerView inside of ViewPager

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a tab layout with each page having a `RecyclerView` inside of it. I'm using `fragments` with `RecyclerView` in them, then i put them inside of `ViewPager`. The problem is that even though tabs are being shown it's content is always empty.

**My Activity class**

```
public class Spells_Act extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager pager;
    private Spells_Slide slider;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spells);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab);
        pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);

        slider = new Spells_Slide(getSupportFragmentManager());
        slider.AddFragment(new Fragment1(), "one");
        slider.AddFragment(new Fragment1(), "two");
        slider.AddFragment(new Fragment1(), "three");

        pager.setAdapter(slider);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    }
}
```

**My ViewPager adapter**

```
public class Spells_Slide extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<RecyclerView> pages;
private List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
private final List<Fragment> stFragment = new ArrayList();
public Spells_Slide(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return stFragment.get(position);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object 
object) {
    return false;
}

public void AddFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    list.add(title);
    stFragment.add(fragment);
}
```

**My Fragment class**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
View v;
private RecyclerView recycler;
Adapter_Rec adapter;
private List<Spells> Spells = new LinkedList<>();


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Spells.add(new Spells("Ghost Sound", "Figment sounds", 0));
    Spells.add(new Spells("Disrupt Undead", " Deals 1d6 damage to one undead", 0));
    Spells.add(new Spells("Resistance", "Subject gains +1 on saving throws", 0));
    Spells.add(new Spells("Ray of Frost", "Ray deals 1d3 cold damage", 0));
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
    recycler = v.findViewById(R.id.frag_recycler);

    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adapter = new Adapter_Rec(Spells, getContext());
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
}
```

And finally my **RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
    public class Adapter_Rec extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Rec.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Spells> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Context context;
    public Adapter_Rec(List<Spells> list, Context context)
    {
    this.context=context;
    this.list=list;
    }

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate
    (R.layout.spells_recycle,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder vholder = new MyViewHolder(v);
return vholder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);


    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.benefits.setText(list.get(position).getDescription());




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView name;
    TextView benefits;

    CheckBox check ;
    public MyViewHolder(View item)
    { super(item);
        name = item.findViewById(R.id.namee);
        benefits = item.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        check =item.findViewById(R.id.check);
    }





}
}
```

Comment: Are your layouts for the RecyclerView ok?

Answer (score 0):

delete isViewFromObject method, or return super.isViewFromObject(view, object);

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object 
object) {
    //return false; // return false will never show this fragment
    return super.isViewFromObject(view, object);
}
```